# looking for a class uml modeling tool that can generate java source

Tags: java, uml

i've used EA by Sparx in the past, but this is too complex for what I need.

What java modelling tool can you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the JUDE community edition.  It used to do the whole round trip, import and export, for Java.  I'm not sure if that's still true since they switched to community and enterprise editions.  It used to be a nice, straightforward tool.

I've used Sparx EA.  I'll agree that it's fairly complex, but if you limit yourself to the straightforward stuff (e.g. class and sequence diagrams) it's not too bad.  What makes you think that another tool will be much better?

Comment: i'm hoping less features = faster performance.  EA is horribly slow on my laptop and I don't want to spend money for a new laptop for the sake of a few UML class diagrams, i'm just cheap that way.

Answer (score 0):

I like [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/).  It provides roundtrip engineering for Java, and code generation for C++, C# and PHP too.  I think IntelliJ provides some UML support, and I'm going to stick my neck out and presume that both Netbeans and Eclipse will have plugins that provide UML modelling too.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Rational Software Architect is a good choice if your company is going to pay for it. It's a very complete tool, but it's quite easy to use and I find it very efficient.